# How to filter rows by percentage of columns over X in R

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, I have a table like such:

ID

A   0   0   1   1

B   0   1   1   0

C   0   1   1   0

D   0   0   0   0

and I want to filter the rows that do not have a 1 in at least half of the columns. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A mean of logical vector is a probability at the same time.

base R Solution:

```r
df[rowMeans(df) < 0.5,]
```

`dplyr`:

```r
dplyr::filter(df, rowMeans(df) < 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
> df
  ID C1 C2 C3 C4
1  A  0  0  1  1
2  B  0  1  1  0
3  C  0  1  1  0
4  D  0  0  0  0
> df %>% mutate(cnt = rowSums(df[-1])) %>% mutate(perc_rows = cnt/ncol(df[-1])) %>% filter(perc_rows < 0.5) %>% select(1:5)
  ID C1 C2 C3 C4
1  D  0  0  0  0
> df %>% mutate(cnt = rowSums(df[-1])) %>% mutate(perc_rows = cnt/ncol(df[-1])) %>% filter(perc_rows >= 0.5) %>% select(1:5)
  ID C1 C2 C3 C4
1  A  0  0  1  1
2  B  0  1  1  0
3  C  0  1  1  0
```

You can change your threshold by changing value in the filter operation.

Comment: Does this only work if the variables are binary? My example had 0s and 1s but is there a way this would work for other dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `base R`solution:

```
df[!rowSums(df == 1) >= ncol(df)/2,]
  A B C D
1 0 0 0 0
4 1 0 0 0
```

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>%
  filter(!rowSums(df == 1) >= ncol(df)/2)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(0,0,1,1),
  B = c(0,1,1,0),
  C = c(0,1,1,0),
  D = c(0,0,0,0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   slice(which(rowMeans(.) < 0.5))
```